# Show mapping based on student access

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table which has following data:

```
student       subject      code
student1      maths        312
student1      physics      785
student2      english      900
student3      geography    317
```

I am trying to restrict access to each student in the table to view data specific to their chosen subject. But there is one restriction to show `maths` data to `student2`. Thereby both `student1` and `student2` both would be able to see `maths` data, and *this mapping has to be done without altering the master data*. So only while displaying the table, `student2` should be mapped to both `english` and `maths`.

Thanks for the help here!

Comment: Why exactly can't you insert a new record with (student2, maths) combination?

Comment: This is a temporary request, so cannot alter the master copy, thanks @Littlefoot

Comment: Use a derived table with (student2, maths) row added.

Comment: This table is quite big with many columns, duplicating might not be possible, thanks @Serg

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```sql
SELECT student, subject, code
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(
           CASE
           WHEN student = :your_student
           OR   (:your_student, subject) IN (('student2', 'maths'))
           THEN 1
           END
         ) OVER (PARTITION BY subject) AS has_access
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  has_access > 0
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (student, subject, code) AS
SELECT 'student1', 'maths',     312 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'student1', 'physics',   785 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'student2', 'english',   900 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'student3', 'geography', 317 FROM DUAL;
```

If `:your_student` is `student1` then the output is:

> | STUDENT | SUBJECT | CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | student1 | maths | 312 |
> | student1 | physics | 785 |

and if `:your_student` is `student2` then the output is:

> | STUDENT | SUBJECT | CODE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | student2 | english | 900 |
> | student1 | maths | 312 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=854d8eb73cd95a406a2c6bfd73468997)*

Answer (score 0):

One option is to - as you said - *temporarily* use `UNION` set operator. Something like this:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (student, subject, code)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT 'student1', 'maths', 312 FROM DUAL
  5         UNION ALL
  6         SELECT 'student1', 'physics', 785 FROM DUAL
  7         UNION ALL
  8         SELECT 'student2', 'english', 900 FROM DUAL
  9         UNION ALL
 10         SELECT 'student3', 'geography', 317 FROM DUAL)
 11  SELECT *
 12    FROM test
 13   WHERE student = '&&par_student'
 14  -- add this to your query
 15  UNION
 16  SELECT 'student2', 'maths', NULL
 17    FROM DUAL
 18   WHERE '&&par_student' = 'student2';
```

---

```
Enter value for par_student: student1  --> student1 is OK, it has two subjects

STUDENT  SUBJECT         CODE
-------- --------- ----------
student1 maths            312
student1 physics          785

SQL> undefine par_student
SQL> /
Enter value for par_student: student2  --> for student2, UNION is used

STUDENT  SUBJECT         CODE
-------- --------- ----------
student2 english          900
student2 maths

SQL> undefine par_student
SQL> /
Enter value for par_student: student3  --> nothing new for student3

STUDENT  SUBJECT         CODE
-------- --------- ----------
student3 geography        317

SQL>
```

---

Depending on tool you use, parameter might look as this (in e.g. TOAD):

```
WHERE student = :par_student
```

or any other way parameters are used in that tool of yours.